# Add HTML on an injected iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a Toolbar from Google Chrome. Basically it's a toolbar that i'm injecting in every web pages by using a Content-Script. Technically the toolbar is materializd by a iframe that include all the components like button, dropMenu,... Here is the script you make this :

```
// Take down the webPage

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginTop = '39px';

var body = $('body'),
toolbarURL = chrome.extension.getURL("yourtoolbar.html"),
iframe = $('<iframe id="YourToolbarFrame" scrolling="no" src="'+toolbarURL+'">');

// Insertion
body.append(iframe);    

// Effect
$("#YourToolbarFrame").hide().fadeIn(800);
```

But right now i'm trying to add some component on this iframe for example a button but it didn't work...

```
var yt = $("#YourToolbarFrame");
var newButton = $('<a href="javascript:openInstantMessage()"><input type="image" src="images/pop.ico" name="InstantMessage" width="23" height="23"></a>');
yt.append(newButton);
```

The body of the iframe look like this :

```
<body>          
    <div class="default">
         // COMPONENTS
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope someone can provide me some help ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait until the iframe loaded. E.g.:

```
iframe.load(function() {  
    var newButton = ...;  
    $(this).contents().find('body').append(newButton);
}).appendTo('body');
```

Not sure how Chrome handles the same-origin policy for content scripts though.

Comment: It din't work, what did you mean by saying 'Chrome same-origin policy' ?

Comment: @Sindar: In a normal websites, you cannot access the content of an iframe if the content comes from a different domain. But as content scripts are something special, it might be possible. Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, 

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL chrome-extension://dkdmapmlfmfkppikamibckkojpofeadp/yourtoolbar.html from frame with URL http://www.valeriemates.com/professional. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
jquery.js:16Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Comment: @Sindar: Oh too bad. Then I guess it is not possible... but why don't you add the button directly to the `yourtoolbar.html` ?

Comment: @Felix Kling: The thing is that this file "yourtoolbar.html" is the basic toolbar. What i need to do is load this file and add the components in function of the person. 

Did you follow me ?

Comment: @Sindar: Mmh.... then I don't know what to do... I'm not that familiar with Chrome extension development... but I will see what I can find out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you could try using

```
$('#YourToolbarFrame').contents().find('body').append(newButton);
```

Or if you don't want to append to the body directly, use any other element in the `find()` statement.