# accessing a <table> of an iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I have seen some articles about accessing the data inside the iframe,So i have in the page that is loading in the iframe a table like this: `<table class="table">...</table>`

so all i want to be displayed in that iframe is this table, **without any headers or other divs or anything**

How can i do this with jQuery ?

UPDATE:

the html code looks like this: i added the table inside a `<div>`

```
<div id="test">
<br>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> ...... // and so on
```

SO, all i want to be displayed in that iframe is this div

UPDATE for **Adil**:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        var filteredContents = $('.test').contents().find('.div_iframe').html();
        $('.test').contents().find('body').html(filteredContents);
});
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<iframe class="test" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=268" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
<iframe class="test" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=260" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
```

and the tables that should be displayed now, they should be two different tables, but at the moment is the same table for both `msjId` but duplicated from the first `msjId`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use jquery load method instead of ready. As load makes sure that the iFrame html is loaded. On the other hand ready makes sure the html elements in the current page are ready.

```
$(window).load(function () {  
      var filteredContents = $('#iframeId').contents().find('.table').html();
      $('#iframeId').contents().find('body').html(filteredContents);
});
```

**Update based on OP request.**

When you have two elements you can use ids instead of class, Please read about **[selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

```
<iframe id="frame1" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=268" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
<iframe id="frame2" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=260" style="height:100%;width:100%;">

 $(window).load(function () {
     var filteredContents1 = $('#frame1').contents().find('.div_iframe').html();
     $('#frame1').contents().find('body').html(filteredContents1);

     var filteredContents2 = $('#frame2').contents().find('.div_iframe').html();
     $('#frame2').contents().find('body').html(filteredContents2);

 });
```

Comment: This will display the text without html tags, Is this you want?

Comment: No, sorry for my mistake, i want to display the <table> tag with everything in it like a html table in that iframe, only the table nothing else

Comment: You have to use this then, $('.table').html();

Comment: i tried this: `$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').contents().find('#table').html();
    });
` but no working

Comment: can you please give a full answer of manipulating this content of the iframe test?

Comment: you are using "#" with table instead of using ".", "#"is used when finding element with id and "." is used with class. I have updated my answer

Comment: still not working, it shows also the headers and all the other stuff :(

Comment: if you update question with complete html and the desired html you want then it will make it easy to get to the solution.

Comment: Check it over here, we do not get contents of div but get only contents of table, http://jsbin.com/agefun/1/edit

Comment: yes, on jsbin is working but on my page the iframe is loading with all headers and stuff,i'm using jQuery 1.2.6

Comment: the alert is giving me `null`

Comment: let me explain again maybe i wasn't so good with the explenation... i have a page that will have numbers of iframes, in this iframes are called other pages that are on the same domain, when i call those pages i need only that table from them because it's a message inbox table...

Comment: UPDATE : the alert is showing right now but how can i display only that table in the iframe? Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: You have to assign it to Iframe , this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243771/add-html-on-an-injected-iframe

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how to put that in the iframe:( , can you update your answer please?

Comment: @Jimmy I have updated my answer with working code. There is a change in event type I used window load event instead of document ready event.

Comment: It works like a charm for one message table, but if i have two message tables that means two iframes it takes the table from the first iframe and duplicate it :( any solution for that? put the dynamic table in a div with a class="div_iframe" but still duplicating it... i will update the answer so you can see how your code is right now on my page...

Comment: Please add new question as we already have change the original to great extent.

Comment: sure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545825/need-like-foreach-in-jquery-to-take-all-the-divs-from-all-the-iframes

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('iframe-id').contents().find('body').html($('.table').html());
```

But the iframe page has to be served from the same domain as your containing page or you'll get a permission denied error.

Comment: doesn't really work, it shows at the beginning of the iframe the mentioned table and then it loads all the page. I'm using this`$(document).ready(function(){ `

Comment: That may be because the iframe hasn't finished loading. Try doing the above in $('#iframe-id').load(function() { /* HERE */ });