# need like foreach in jQuery to take all the divs from all the iframes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, iframe

so the code that extracts the div from the iframe is made by @Adil like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        var filteredContents = $('.test').contents().find('.div_iframe').html();
        $('.test').contents().find('body').html(filteredContents);
});
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<iframe class="test" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=268" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
<iframe class="test" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=260" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
```

and the tables that should be displayed now, they should be two different tables, but at the moment is the same table for both `msjId` but duplicated from the first `msjId`...

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

i will explain more so i don't get `close vote` what i'm doing is that i have a table in the iframes that i want only to get without any headers or anything so the code above is filtering that to give me exactly that div that contains the table from the iframe and then displays it. my problem is if i have more than one iframe then the table is duplicated from the first iframe with the same info and there's no loop like `foreach`...

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's "each" method.

Comment: @jimp i don't really know how to use `each` in my case ... can you help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more then one elements you can use each to iterate through them, try this.

```
<iframe id="frame1" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=268" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
<iframe id="frame2" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=260" style="height:100%;width:100%;">

 $(window).load(function () {
     $('.test').each(function(){         

       var filteredContents1 = $(this).contents().find('.div_iframe').html();
       $(this).contents().find('body').html(filteredContents1);       

     });

 });
```

Comment: yes, but it's a dynamic call of the iframe so i can't make ids, my iframe looks like this: `<iframe id="frame2" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?<? echo $id ?>" style="height:100%;width:100%;">`

Comment: need help with your code if i do submit action on iframe need to take the next msjId, is it possible ?

Comment: what i mean is simply if i make an action on the iframe and it reloads then it reloads with all the headers and i want it to reloads like before with only that part, even i don't reload the page and only the iframe reload, do you know what i mean ?

Comment: After making action you need to execute these statements for every frame that is loaded  var filteredContents1 = $(this).contents().find('.div_iframe').html();
       $(this).contents().find('body').html(filteredContents1);

Comment: yes, but how can i do this without reloading the page, i want just the iframe to reload as i wanted without headers :( ?

Comment: i tried a lot of methods from here but nothing is working :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: Yes you can do that without loading the frame, what action you perform on that iframe?

Comment: no, within the iframe html there's a button after that table you know of submit, so if i click submit it submits but reload just the iframe and doesn't apply the script you made anymore because the window is not reloaded :(

Comment: you can answer there so i can accept you answer for this too, need help :( thanks man ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564684/actions-within-the-iframe-breaks-my-script-jquery