# actions within the iframe breaks my script jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html, iframe

i have a script that cuts a part of the iframe( iframe without headers ) and shows it. my problem is if i make actions within this iframe, the iframe reloads but is not applying the jquery filtering to give me only that part but instad gives me all the page with headers so i'm assuming that script is not working when it reload the iframe without the window reload of the main page that has the iframe:

```
<iframe class="test" width="100%" height="100%" src="/message.html?msjId=260" style="height:100%;width:100%;">

 $(window).load(function () {
     $('.test').each(function(){         

       var filteredContents1 = $(this).contents().find('.div_iframe').html();
       $(this).contents().find('body').html(filteredContents1);       

     });

 });
```

any solutions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add load events for frames as well. Add the load event in document.ready function as given below. If it works you may be able to omit window load event you already have for filtering frames data.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){     
      $('.test').load(function () {

         var filteredContents1 = $('#frame1').contents().find('#divChild').html();
         $('#frame1').contents().find('body').html(filteredContents1);

      });
  });
```

Update on request of questioner

```
  $(document).ready(function(){     
      $('.test').load(function () {            

         $('#frame1, #frame2, #frame3').each(function(){
             var filteredContents1 = $(this).contents().find('#divChild').html();
             $(this).contents().find('body').html(filteredContents1);
         });            

      });
  });
```

.

Comment: As always @Adil you are a genius! thanks very much for helping here too!

Comment: can you please Adil update this answer with another code that supports the `.each` if i had more than one iframe please ? because right now it shows 3 identical iframes.. i appreciate it a lot

Comment: please can you help me with " i want to add a custom function in javascript to be executed when click on submit button"? i will make a question if you can help me, or maybe you can start a chat room please and we talk there please

Comment: You will get many good answers if you put the question you can try this and tell me so that I can delete this comment when you are done $(document).ready(function(){     
      $('#yourbuttonId').click(function () { alert("clicked me"); }); });

Comment: it won't work this way because the execution is inside the iframe so it will be like: `onload="parent.myFunction()"`, but the problem is that i can't get myFunction call. i mean i have like this `$('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(0).after('<tr><td colspan=10><iframe class="icontent" src="/message.html?msgId='+$('.table').eq(1).find('tbody td a').eq(0).text()+'&constant=1"></iframe></td></tr>');` and don't know how to call, or define the function..:( can we talk in a chat room please ?

Comment: Okay put your question, If you do not get answer soon, then tell me I will try it for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673343/form-not-submiting-with-jquery-hide-in-it

Comment: can you please check the question, no body gave an answer at all, and i don't think it's really that hard but i just don't know it my self